# Can I use a combobox in a programmatically bound datagrid C#

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am using entity framework and binding to a datagrid to display the results of my query.  Instead of showing the foreign key from the result, I would like to show the more meaningful value from the lookup table and limit the users input by using a combobox too.

Is it possible to use a combobox in a programmatically bound datagrid on a winform?  If so - how?

Thanks in advance,

James

Comment: I cant find anything on the internet regarding this question.  Am I taking the wrong GUI approach or is it really that difficult?

Answer (score 0):

There is a column type for a combobox in a DataGridView:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx

For changing the display value you can use this event:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx